# Datatype mismatch sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite

```
PostData postData = new PostData()
 {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        MessageId = msg.MessageId,
        Post_url = photo, 
        PostId = instance.PostId
 };

using (IDbConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=DB.db", true))
{
conn.Execute("INSERT INTO PostData (Id, Post_url, PostId, MessageId)" +
"VALUES (@Id, @Post_url, @PostId, @MessageId)",/* new { id, photo, instance.PostId, msg.MessageId }*/ postData);
}
```

- вот мой запрос, при выполнении пишет "datatype missmatch"

http://prntscr.com/oqvhki - Вот типы в БД
Как отметить в БД ID чтобы гуид кушал его как верный тип?